# How to import nodes from one document to another without appending

Tags: java, xml, dom

I need register nodes from one document (doc1) to another document (doc2) with deep copy (attribute, ns information, etc.) in order to fix getElementById problem in Java 8. 
Thus I only need those nodes registered in doc2 without appending them into the parent node. The Document API of adoptNode, and importNode [Document API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode-org.w3c.dom.Node-boolean-)  requires appending the target nodes into doc2 which modifies dom structure of doc2. Is there any work around to register nodes without appending.

```
public void testAddNodesToDocument() throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    InputStream payloadData = new ByteArrayInputStream( "<Wrapper><TagA Id=\"attributeId\" Target=\"SomeTarges\">test</TagA></Wrapper>".getBytes() );
    Document doc = builder.parse( payloadData );

    setAttributeId( doc );
    assertNotNull( doc.getElementById( "attributeId" ) );

    Document newDoc = builder.newDocument();
    Element nodeList = doc.getDocumentElement();
    Node result = newDoc.importNode( nodeList, true );
    // if appendChild is commnented out, the assertion of getElementById fails
    // newDoc.appendChild( result );
    setAttributeId(newDoc);
    assertNotNull( "getElementsByTagName doesn't work, element is not imported!", newDoc.getElementsByTagName( "TagA" ) );
    assertNotNull( "getElementById doesn't work!", newDoc.getElementById( "attributeId" ) );
}

private void setAttributeId( Document doc )
{
    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName( "*" );

    for( int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++ )
    {
        Node node = list.item( i );
        if( node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE )
        {
            // do something with the current element
            org.w3c.dom.Element item = (Element)node;
            Attr idAttr = item.getAttributeNode( "Id" );
            if( idAttr != null )
            {
                item.setIdAttributeNode( idAttr, true );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why using `Node importedNode = doc2.importNode(node1, true);` involves any appending to parent nodes. I also don't understand what "register nodes" exactly means. Perhaps you can explain with a code snippet what you do, which error message(s) you get, which result you want, which result you currently get.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, I updated sample code. I want getElementById also works in doc2 without breaking the original doc2 dom structure.

Comment: Well, `newDoc.getElementById` looks for elements by id in the `newDoc` tree, if there are no such elements in the tree why should `getElementById` find them? I you have nodes not attached to a tree then `document.getElementById` does not find them, whether you have used two different document and importNode or just a single document is not important. So I am not sure what you want to achieve or expect `getElementById` to do, do you expect it to return any elements by id owned by the particular document? That is not the case.

Comment: @MartinHonnen well, the root cause for me doing this beyond this topic, if it helps you to understand the background, I need this works in a XML Digital Signature, merge some nodes into an original doc which contains the data supposed to be signed, that's why I can't break the original dom structure. I tried creating individual element from doc1 without appending the element to doc1, it works. I'm searching for possibility to merge nodes into doc1 to achieve the same result of creating individual elements.

Comment: The *"without breaking the original doc2 dom structure"* part should be fulfilled by `importNode`.

Comment: @the8472 I'm afraid you didn't understand the question, neither answered it.